# Entering data into a datagrid

Tags: vb.net, vba

I am using Visual Basic 2008. I am trying to enter 2 columns of text into a datagrid using a `button`.

When i press the button a variable and a data associated to the variable should be entered into 2 columns of datagrid.

The code i am using is:

```
Public Class Entering_the_rates
Public Class Datagrid

    Private category As String
    Public Property getcategory() As String
        Get
            Return category
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            category = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private price As Decimal
    Public Property getprice() As Decimal
        Get
            Return price
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
            price = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class


Private Sub Entering_the_rates_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    datagridadult() as new Datagrid (category, price) 

End Sub
End Class
```

is this syntax right or wrong.
I also need a sample code on how to call a datagrid i have declared . Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a constructor in your class:

```
Public Class Datagrid

Private _category As String
Public Property getcategory() As String
    Get
        Return category
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        category = value
    End Set
End Property

Private _price As Decimal
Public Property getprice() As Decimal
    Get
        Return price
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
        price = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New(byval category as string, byval price as decimal)
    _category = category
    _price = price
End Sub

End Class
```

Your private variables behind your properties should start with an underscore too, see here: http://10rem.net/articles/net-naming-conventions-and-programming-standards---best-practices this makes assigning them in the constructor easier. You could also use autoimplemented properties, these auto create the _ behind variables for you (though they do not show in intellisense).

Comment: could you please tell me how to call the Datgrid now?........         My code to call it was                                                      `code`                                                              as           Dim adultDatagrid() As Datagrid = _
             New Datagrid("Adults", adult) _
            DataGridView1.DataSource = adultDatagrid
`code`                                                              This was not working. I got a error "End of Statement expected" for the line "DataGridView1.DataSource = adultDatagrid". Can you please correct me?????

Comment: What are you trying to do? Assign a datasource to a datagrid to display in a form somewhere? If so you don't just write your own datagrid class, its an MS control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx